# Unable to find a specification in CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, cocoapods

I cannot understand why the Cocoapod is unable to find the pod specification I created when I run `pod install`. Could someone help me solve this trouble?

I'm defining a subspec in my library podspec file like this:

```
s.subspec 'mysubspec' do |c|
  c.dependency 'ABC','1.0.0'
end
```

This dependency ABC is listed in the library Podfile:

```
pod 'ABC', :git => 'git@github.com:myrepo/Podspecs.git', :branch => 'xyz'
```

The Podspec file `ABC.podspec` in the branch xyz of myrepo/Podspecs seems like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "ABC"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "git@github.com:myrepo/Podspecs.git", :branch => "xyz" }
end
```

The error is `[!] Unable to find a specification for ABC (= 1.0.0)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of:

```
s.source       = { :git => "git@github.com:myrepo/Podspecs.git", :branch => "xyz" }
```

Write this:
Don't forget the tag...

```
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/myrepo/Podspecs.git", :branch => "xyz",
                   :tag => s.version.to_s }
```

Comment: U have to tell the pod which tag r u talking. It's a must.

Comment: Simply, add tag to your last commit

Comment: I'll try it. Unfortunately, it's not in the Podspec documentation.

Comment: It did not solve the problem: `[!] Unable to find a specification for `ABC (= 1.0.0)`

Comment: Can u please add to your question your podspec file?

Comment: I solved the problem! I have to import the pod ABC before importing the subspec.

Comment: `:tag` is *not* required

Answer (score 189):

I suppose that there is a problem with your pod master repo. Delete it and download it again.

You can do:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Or:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: Just running `pod setup` did the job.

Comment: For me, only running the remove line first solved the problem! Took a while to setup though.

Comment: Wow! This. For some reason my Spec master repo wasn't setup correctly and I had to remove it this way and then did the setup and install. Thanks for this!

Comment: 'pod setup' took quite a while, but was all I needed (as Rao mentioned)

Comment: Tried multiple other solutions, this is the one that did it for me (first solution)

Comment: Might want to try `pod repo update && pod setup` first - if your repo is just missing specs this might fix it and will be faster than re-cloning the whole repo from scratch.

Comment: This is working, for the first time only. After restart / pod install in another project... fail fail fail again. 
use tis method instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287082/using-private-pod-and-public-pod-in-the-same-project/50618926#50618926

Comment: It may be called `trunk` rather than `master`, in case you get 'repo master does not exist'

Answer (score 43):

For me it was an issue with finding the spec, not the spec itself. I needed to add a source link to the Podfile, see [Podfile documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html)

Cocoapods recently added the need to link to the repo that holds the pod spec file you are looking for, the default is:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

You may need to add multiple source links if you are using more obscure or homemade pods.

Comment: This can't be a requirement (at least not with the latest release), because I have not needed to added source links and after following Gastón's suggestion all worked fine.

Comment: @sinewave440hz, adding the source is most often used when you need to access a nonstandard private `.git` repo.  The default source is public.

Comment: I see, thanks (not that I remember writing any of that, but I'm sure it will help someone somewhere :D)

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you added

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

at the very beginning of your Podfile

Comment: This is especially relevant if you want to add a private pod.

Answer (score 7):

I resolve this after add

```
source '/Users/username/Documents/path/to/iOS_SpecsRepository'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

to Podfile.
well .I used a local repository as my Repo. So i can user this in another podspec file

```
s.dependency 'iOS_Networking_CPN', '~> 0.1.1'
```

`iOS_Networking_CPN` is in the local path.

Comment: source '/Users/username/Documents/path/to/iOS_SpecsRepository' worked, do you know why I have to use a local source path?

Comment: in my opinion,because every device need a local repository for a podspec

Answer (score 7):

With me, this worked like a charm.

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
```

However, you may try directly, `pod setup` as some users pointed.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting similar error for *MGBoxkit*

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `MGBoxkit`

By replacing the following line

```
pod 'MGBoxkit'
```

with

```
pod 'MGBoxKit'
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: Typo as k was replaced with K.

Answer (score 4):

Update the master repo for cocoapods.

```
pod repo update master
```

Answer (score 3):

You first need to add your Podspec to a private specs repo; this lets CocoaPods find the pod when you try to install it.

Enter the following in Terminal, making sure you’re still in the framework directory you are trying to add:

```
pod repo add [your framework name] [Your framework Git URL]
pod repo push [your framework name] [your framework .podspec file name]
```

Comment: Doesnt feel true when the pod is hosted on `trunk`

Answer (score 1):

I missed adding `,` causing issue.

Replacing,

```
pod 'PodName' '~> 2.3'
```

With,

```
pod 'PodName', '~> 2.3'
```

Did the job.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with below command:

cocoa pod update

To update use this command

**sudo gem install cocoapods**

if above command gives error than use this one

**sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods**

and than do this

**pod repo update**

Answer (score 1):

I was working in flutter with all public repos. I was getting a similar error:

```
Unable to find a specification for `TOCropViewController (~> 2.5.2)` depended upon by `image_cropper`
```

For some reason `TOCropViewController` specification was unavailable. I tried the following:

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
rm ios/Podfile
flutter run
```

But the plugin specification was still unavailable. Finally, I solved it by removing the pod's repo master.

```
pod repo remove master
sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos
pod setup
pod install
```

To validate and confirm that the plugin is here, I tried `grep` inside `.cocoapods`, using:

```
 grep -r "TOCropViewController" -n ~/.cocoapods
```

Inside `~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/3/7/4/TOCropViewController/2.5.2/TOCropViewController.podspec.json`

I found the plugin's git repo and correct version number.

```
  "source": {
    "git": "https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController.git",
    "tag": "2.5.2"
  },
```

After that `flutter clean` and `flutter run` started working.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add these two lines at the beginning of the Podfile:

```js
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/goinstant/pods-specs-public'
```

Then run `pod install` again.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem.

what really worked for me was `gem uninstall cocoapods` (as mentioned above by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4264880/seema-sharma) where I found that I had 11 (!) different cocoapods versions installed.

I chose to uninstall all and then `gem install cocoapods:1.4.0`

All good now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the below worked well but first try could be direct "pod setup" command If that don't work then go for the below commands would definitely make things happen.

**pod repo remove master 

  pod setup 

  pod install**

Comment: How does this differ from @gastón-antonio-montes's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850706/1998086)?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps :

**Step 0:** `pod repo update master`

**Step 1:** `pod install`

And you are done!

Answer (score 0):

use tis instead.
[Using private pod and public pod in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287082/using-private-pod-and-public-pod-in-the-same-project/50618926#50618926)

add the souce for both private and public(official) in the beginning of the podfile.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped me. Ultimately i figured out that I had a **typo spelling mistake for one of the Pods**.

Ex:- `Firebaseresulrereres/Analytics`. It was supposed to be `Firebase/Analytics` but without my knowledge the pod name had a wrong spelling like `Firebaseresulrereres/Analytics`.

**Correcting the Pod Name did the trick for me!**. It cost me 1 hour to find this though!. Development can be ambiguous and frustrating some times! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
pod update
```

Solved the same error in my case.