# Unable to install pods using a legacy Cocoapods version

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Working an a iOS project and don't have time to fix potential pod conflicts, getting the following error when running '`pod install`'

```
The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 -  (currently using 0.39.0)
```

Using `--no-repo-update` flag seems to help but throws another warning

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6163

```
Unable to find specification for
```

... manually replaced te  pod master repo .. but didn't work ..

[Unable to find a specification in CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913733/unable-to-find-a-specification-in-cocoapods)

Being forced to use the latest version ... (`--verbose` .. also states that I need to update)

[when running pod install I get The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.32.1, try updating but still in 0.31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165446/when-running-pod-install-i-get-the-master-repo-requires-cocoapods-0-32-1-try)

Comment: If you don't want to update the CocoaPods version and want to continue with older one then use the source `source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs"` at top of your pod file as given here http://blog.cocoapods.org/Sharding/

Comment: @iHulk Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As iHulk states in his comment:

Use `source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs"` at top of your pod file

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in your terminal

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```