# Unable to find a specification for CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I had problem at install cocoa-pods

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `SideMenu~> 2.0`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find a specification in CocoaPods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913733/unable-to-find-a-specification-in-cocoapods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. But I've got to fix my issue with the following procedure.

```
   source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
    platform :ios, '9.0'

    target 'Test' do

      use_frameworks!

#    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
     pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'

#    pod 'SwiftyJSON' , '~> 3.1'
     pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'

#     pod 'SideMenu' '~> 2.0'
      pod 'SideMenu', :git => 'https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu.git'

#     pod 'SDWebImage', '4.0.0-beta2'
      pod 'SDWebImage', :git => 'https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git'

#     pod 'SwiftDate', '~> 4.0'
      pod 'SwiftDate', :git => 'https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate'



end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
     end
    end
  end
```

[Links for more information](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Comment: but for pods like Firebase/Core that you don't find on Github if not on the official website, which you would have to put in the: git

Answer (score 0):

The specs repo is recently being sharded:

http://blog.cocoapods.org/Sharding/

If you don't use the latest CoacoPods:

Use `source https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs` at top of your pod file

I experienced the same:

[Unable to install pods using a legacy Cocoapods version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633770/unable-to-install-pods-using-a-legacy-cocoapods-version)