# Can't install BraintreeDropIn through cocoapod 'Unable to find a specification for `BraintreeDropIn`'

Tags: ios, cocoapods, braintree, braintree-sandbox

Unable to install BraintreeDropIn through cocoapod.

I'm getting the error

> Unable to find a specification for **BraintreeDropIn**.

In my podfile,

```
pod 'BraintreeDropIn'
```

Comment: github/cocoa link?

Comment: @sasquatch i checked in github says pod 'BraintreeDropIn'. Still not working

Comment: I just tried it and was able to successfully install BraintreeDropIn (5.0.1)

Comment: i am using # platform :ios, '9.0' and xcode 7.3 and ios 9.3

Comment: I am using the same, it works. You have to provide more information before anyone can help you on this

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32850706/3207014

Comment: I am using xcode 7.3 and created a new project. Using terminal i created pod file and used pod 'BraintreeDropIn' and running pod install command in terminal then i am getting Unable to find a specification for BraintreeDropIn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131019/discussion-between-sasquatch-and-vjvj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in chats, this problem was solved by doing

`pod setup`