# Using private pod and public pod in the same project

Tags: ios, git, dependencies, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.2

I've just pushed a private pod to `my.domain.com:apps/MyPrivatePod.git`. I'd like to use both this private pod and other public pods in my project

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Testing' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.0 ' // This is supposed to be a public Pod
  pod 'MyPrivatePod', '~> 1.1' // This is the private pod I talked about
end
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

After Cocoapods 1.7.2+ release, right answer in `Podfile`

```
source '<PRIVATE_POD_SPEC_URL>'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

Comment: This is the way! I have tried to use `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`, it clones and process for way too long time. By using `source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'` it works smoothly!

Comment: I was struggling since 2 days. This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have built the private pod refer to [the official docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) and push it to your private spec index repo, for example, `https://bitbucket.org/<your-name>/specs.git`.

After that, add the spec index repo url into your `Podfile`.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'   # the official index spec
source 'https://bitbucket.org/<your-name>/specs.git'  # your private index spec
```

Now use them as usual.

```
target 'foo-target' do
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 3.2'    # public pod, cloned from cocoapods/specs.git
    pod 'MyPrivatePod', '~> 1.1'       # private pod, cloned from your private specs.git
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is the only solution that works for adding private and public repo together in one pod file.
as well as if you have private pod where you want to use another private pod as a dependency then also this solution works.

Thanks Itachi

Comment: THX! best anz. using the pod repo add method is really a pain in the xxx for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this and change the path for your private pod path

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Testing' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.0 ' // This is supposed to be a public Pod
  pod 'MyPrivatePod', '~> 1.1' , :path => 'libraries/MyPrivatePod/'
end
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you have private specs, then source url like this 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/' instead of 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

[CocoaPods-1.7.2](https://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.7.2/)